# project build failed in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

while I installed android studio I faced so many errors! the last one is in building the project and I got this error I don't know how to fix it:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugAndroidTestApkCopy'.
>   Could not resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3.
>        Required by:
>            MyApplication:app:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
>   Could not resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3.
>   Could not get resource 'https: //jcenter.bintray.com/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/hamcrest-library-1.3.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https: //jcenter.bintray.com/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/hamcrest-library-1.3.pom'.
>   jcenter.bintray.com
>   Could not resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3.
>        Required by:
>            MyApplication:app:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
>   Could not resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-integration/1.3/hamcrest-integration-1.3.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https: //jcenter.bintray.com/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-integration/1.3/hamcrest-integration-1.3.pom'.
>   jcenter.bintray.com

Comment: do u have active internet connection

Comment: No my bad! now I have internet connection and its done! thanks

Comment: glad that helped